# call the first feature from the second feature file, failed without specified clue

Tags: karate

Run the first.feature file successfully，however， call it from the second.feature failed without any clue to analysis. Do you have any idea help me find the root cause?

**The source of my first.feature:**

```
Feature: 采样管理-样本登记

  Background: 读取随机生成的条形码、手机号、采样类型等作为入参
    * url baseURL

    * def randomData = Java.type('utils.RandomData')
    * def barcode = randomData.getRandom(11)
    * def randomPhone = randomData.getTelephone()
    * def sampletype = randomData.getNum(0,1)

  Scenario: 输入合法参数进行正常样本登记，确认能够登记成功

    Given path 'iEhr/PersonSample'
#    * header Content-type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    * cookies { JSESSIONID: '#(jsessionID)',SESSION: '#(sessionID)', ACMETMP: '#(acmetmpID)'}
    * def autoMotherName = "autoMname"+ barcode

#    * def confData = {mothername: "#(autoMotherName)", barcode: "#(barcode)", mobile: '#(randomPhone)', sampletype:"#(sampletype)" }
#   设置sampletype为1，已被采样
    * def confData = {mothername: "#(autoMotherName)", barcode: "#(barcode)", mobile: '#(randomPhone)', sampletype:"1" }
#    打印入参变量输出
    * print confData

#    用例与数据分离
    * def paramObj = read('classpath:mainFlow/sampleSaveReqTest.json')
    * print paramObj
    * form field param = paramObj

    When method post

    Then status 200
    * json result = response[0].result
    * def personId = result[0].personid
    * def sampleid = result[0].sampleid
    * print personId
    * print sampleid
```

**The source of my second.feature:**

```
Feature: 提交递送样本
  Background:

    * def sampleResult = call read('classpath:mainFlow/first.feature')
    * print sampleResult
```

I run the first.feature singly， it works. However, karate reports the error below after running the second.feature. Any idea how can I debug to find the root cause? I have no idea what's wrong with the second read.  Many thanks!

```
* def sampleResult = call read('classpath:mainFlow/first.feature')
```

-unknown-:14 - javascript evaluation failed: read('classpath:mainFlow/first.feature'), null

Comment: I see few variables need to be passed as input for first.feature, are those passed from your second.feature or at least in the scope of second.feature?

Comment: all my feature files and json data files are resided in the same folder. And I can run successfully when singly running the fist.feature. However, I didn't pass any variables from the second.feature, because I think when calling the first.feature, it is the responsibility of the first.feature who should get variables passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for some issue with `karate-config.js`. As Babu said in the comments, it is very hard to make out what the problem is, I suggest you follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Also try if the latest preview version 0.9.3.RC2 is better at showing what the error is.

If you can replicate the problem as a small example, it will help us - because we really need to do better at showing more useful error logs, instead of just `null`.

Comment: I can not replicate the problem right now. I will submit an issue once I get it replicated. Thanks~~

Comment: Probably a classpath issue. Also, @Peter does Karate accept contributions?

Comment: @AshikVetrivelu yes